# resolve Merge conflict with subversive

Tags: eclipse, merge, subversive

How to resolve a merge conflict when merging a branch back to trunk with subversive. (e.g a File have different changes at the same position)

i did the folowing:

- selected merge at a project (team merge)
- selected branch url
- execute merge
  ==> conflicts are now shown in syncronize view
- select resolve conflict 
  ==>Conflicts are shown in the Compare view
- edit the working copy to resolve one conflict

So far it worked but now i want to save the working copy and show the remaining conflicts in that file.
But when i save the working copy the conflict view is not updated. And when i reopen the conflict view i didnt see my previous changes. That makes it impossible to resolve conflicts.

thx for helping

(Eclipse 3.6, subverive 0.7.9, svnkit 1.3.5)
i use the newest subverive version and svnkit

Answer (score 0):

You just need to right click on the file; team --> mark as merged